# Trusty OpenStack Kilo on Juju MAAS fails to create instance

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

Ubuntu Trusty 14.04.2 LTS on MAAS controller and using Juju, the Dashboard and the juju-gui console.

No matter what I try, I can't get an instance to spin up.  It looks like I have a nova-scheduler and four available hypervisors but maybe the scheduler can't be reached.  The image was downloaded from [Cloud Images: trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img)  Since this is a completely private cloud I'm not using any of the Neutron-related services, for what it's worth.

```
me@controller:~$ nova service-list
+----------------+----------------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------+
| Binary         | Host                 | Zone     | Status  | State | Updated_at                 | Disabled Reason |
+----------------+----------------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------+
| nova-cert      | juju-machine-3-lxc-1 | internal | enabled | up    | 2015-09-23T20:09:35.000000 | -               |
| nova-conductor | juju-machine-3-lxc-1 | internal | enabled | up    | 2015-09-23T20:09:36.000000 | -               |
| nova-scheduler | juju-machine-3-lxc-1 | internal | enabled | up    | 2015-09-23T20:09:35.000000 | -               |
| nova-compute   | psi                  | nova     | enabled | up    | 2015-09-23T20:09:31.000000 | -               |
| nova-compute   | gamma                | nova     | enabled | up    | 2015-09-23T20:09:35.000000 | -               |
| nova-compute   | delta                | nova     | enabled | up    | 2015-09-23T20:09:38.000000 | -               |
| nova-network   | psi                  | internal | enabled | up    | 2015-09-23T20:09:33.000000 | -               |
| nova-network   | gamma                | internal | enabled | up    | 2015-09-23T20:09:36.000000 | -               |
| nova-network   | delta                | internal | enabled | up    | 2015-09-23T20:09:38.000000 | -               |
| nova-compute   | chi                  | nova     | enabled | up    | 2015-09-23T20:09:29.000000 | -               |
| nova-network   | chi                  | internal | enabled | up    | 2015-09-23T20:09:29.000000 | -               |
+----------------+----------------------+----------+---------+-------+----------------------------+-----------------+
```

.

```
me@controller:~$ nova host-list
+----------------------+-----------+----------+
| host_name            | service   | zone     |
+----------------------+-----------+----------+
| juju-machine-3-lxc-1 | cert      | internal |
| juju-machine-3-lxc-1 | conductor | internal |
| juju-machine-3-lxc-1 | scheduler | internal |
| psi                  | compute   | nova     |
| gamma                | compute   | nova     |
| delta                | compute   | nova     |
| psi                  | network   | internal |
| gamma                | network   | internal |
| delta                | network   | internal |
| chi                  | compute   | nova     |
| chi                  | network   | internal |
+----------------------+-----------+----------+
```

.

```
me@controller:~$ nova hypervisor-list
+----+---------------------+
| ID | Hypervisor hostname |
+----+---------------------+
| 1  | psi.maas            |
| 2  | gamma.maas          |
| 3  | delta.maas          |
| 4  | chi.maas            |
+----+---------------------+
```

.

```
me@controller:~$ nova hypervisor-stats
+----------------------+-------+
| Property             | Value |
+----------------------+-------+
| count                | 4     |
| current_workload     | 0     |
| disk_available_least | 312   |
| free_disk_gb         | 365   |
| free_ram_mb          | 9818  |
| local_gb             | 365   |
| local_gb_used        | 0     |
| memory_mb            | 11866 |
| memory_mb_used       | 2048  |
| running_vms          | 0     |
| vcpus                | 8     |
| vcpus_used           | 0     |
+----------------------+-------+
```

.

```
me@controller:~$ glance image-show a21494c2-781d-4c55-a540-205bd5fb95c1
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Property                | Value                                |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Property 'architecture' | x86_64                               |
| Property 'description'  | trusty amd64 x86_64                  |
| checksum                | b5166b7ad4daea665e5d30bd5080f7fd     |
| container_format        | bare                                 |
| created_at              | 2015-09-23T19:15:14.000000           |
| deleted                 | False                                |
| disk_format             | qcow2                                |
| id                      | a21494c2-781d-4c55-a540-205bd5fb95c1 |
| is_public               | True                                 |
| min_disk                | 0                                    |
| min_ram                 | 0                                    |
| name                    | trusty-amd64-x86_64                  |
| owner                   | 76f1f9f5be51439ab09252c9f2dfa443     |
| protected               | False                                |
| size                    | 258540032                            |
| status                  | active                               |
| updated_at              | 2015-09-23T19:22:06.000000           |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

In the Dashboard, the error message is:

```
Error:  Failed to perform requested operation on instance "small-1", the instance has an error status: Please try again later [Error: No valid host was found. Exceeded max scheduling attempts 3 for instance fb050155-be21-4dcc-89f2-0730e5dfc5db. Last exception: [u'Traceback (most recent call last):\n', u' File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2235, in _do].
```

Attempting to review the status of that nova-conductor:

```
me@controller:~$ juju status nova-cloud-controller
environment: private
machines:
  "3":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.24.5
    dns-name: delta.maas
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-1884bef4-609f-11e5-aa64-001d097b3221/
    series: trusty
    containers:
      3/lxc/1:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.24.5
        dns-name: 10.100.100.56
        instance-id: juju-machine-3-lxc-1
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=2 mem=4096M
services:
  nova-cloud-controller:
    charm: cs:trusty/nova-cloud-controller-60
    can-upgrade-to: cs:trusty/nova-cloud-controller-62
    exposed: false
    service-status:
      current: unknown
      since: 22 Sep 2015 10:55:37-07:00
    relations:
      amqp:
      - rabbitmq-server
      cinder-volume-service:
      - cinder
      cloud-compute:
      - nova-compute
      cluster:
      - nova-cloud-controller
      identity-service:
      - keystone
      image-service:
      - glance
      shared-db:
      - mysql
    units:
      nova-cloud-controller/0:
        workload-status:
          current: unknown
          since: 22 Sep 2015 10:55:37-07:00
        agent-status:
          current: idle
          since: 23 Sep 2015 11:53:14-07:00
          version: 1.24.5
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.24.5
        machine: 3/lxc/1
        open-ports:
        - 3333/tcp
        - 8773/tcp
        - 8774/tcp
        public-address: 10.100.100.56
networks:
  maas-eth0:
    provider-id: maas-eth0
    cidr: 10.100.100.0/24
```

On what is supposed to be the nova-scheduler node:

```
ubuntu@machine3: sudo cat /var/log/nova/nova-compute.log
2015-09-22 17:49:34.045 43291 ERROR oslo_messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-9acbcd62-a66b-4b9f-a7bc-9253c6d26d9d - - - - -] AMQP server on 127.0.0.1:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Trying again in 2 seconds.
2015-09-22 17:57:20.144 66453 WARNING nova.conductor.api [req-37c37533-4c68-42d2-9444-ba5fc4ae1666 - - - - -] Timed out waiting for nova-conductor.  Is it running? Or did this service start before nova-conductor?  Reattempting establishment of nova-conductor connection...
2015-09-22 18:01:26.145 76457 WARNING nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-f8bc084a-d627-4463-91c2-521b421e075f - - - - -] Cannot update service status on host "delta" since it is not registered.
2015-09-22 18:01:27.002 76457 WARNING nova.compute.resource_tracker [req-f8bc084a-d627-4463-91c2-521b421e075f - - - - -] No compute node record for delta:delta.maas
2015-09-22 18:01:27.913 76457 INFO oslo_messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [req-f8bc084a-d627-4463-91c2-521b421e075f - - - - -] Connecting to AMQP server on 10.100.100.58:5672
```

I've tried to change the virt-type to qemu in the Dashboard but that setting doesn't appear to be making it out to the /etc/nova/nova.conf files on the four hypervisors.  I manually set it on the four hypervisors via ssh but it's back to the previous layout which doesn't include the line after [libvirt]:

```
virt-type = qemu
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change /etc/nova/nova-compute.conf instead of nova.conf.
Usually there is a value virt-type = kvm

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.  (It might take a day or two.)